# Is there a simple way to perform subtraction between two nodesets in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Please note**: this question is very similar to a number of other questions I've found here, yet it's **not duplicate**, so please read carefully:

Essentially I want to exclude node and all of it's descendants from a collection by (say) class name.

The extension I made (check the snippet) works perfect in a given example, however I'm willing to find easier/more elegant way to do it (if it exists in jquery currently).

I'm lookig for a **generic** way to perform `$(this).find('<some_selector>').exclude_found_nodes_that_have_the_following_between_aforementioned_this_and_itself('<exclusion_selector>')`, however
something like `$(this).find('<exclusion_selector>:ignore_branch_if_this_node_met() <some_selector>')` would do the job too.

IDs are not actually present in the code, they're added purely for demonstrational purposes ("starting node" gets picked by user).

```js
$.fn.find_exclude = function(original_selector,exclude_selector) {
  var counter=$(this).parents(exclude_selector).length;
  if ($(this).is(exclude_selector)){
    counter++;
  }
  var tmp=$(this).find(original_selector); 
  return tmp.filter(function(){
      if($(this).is(exclude_selector) || $(this).parents(exclude_selector).length>counter){
        return false;
    }
      return true
    });
};

$(function(){
  var all_b_in_main_not_in_groups=$("#main").find_exclude('b','.group');
  var all_b_in_inner_not_in_groups=$("#inner").find_exclude('b','.group');
  
  all_b_in_main_not_in_groups.each(function(){
    $(this).css('color','red');
  });
  all_b_in_inner_not_in_groups.each(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity','0.5');
  });
  
  
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="main">
<b>I should be red</b>
<div class="group" id="inner">
  <span>
    <b>I should be opaque but not red</b>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <b>I should be red</b>
  <div class="group">
     <b>Don't touch me, please.</b>
        <div>
          <b>Don't touch me, please.</b>
            <p>
              <b>Don't touch me, please.</b>
            </p>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
</span>
```

**WARNING: Before proposing just using `:not` or `.not()`, or even some use of `.clone()`, please reread the question and a given example once again and check if your solution really works - the proposed solution should work with both `#main` and `#inner` as starting nodes (without actually knowing the starting node selector - they are known as `$(this)` inside `click` event listener)**

Comment: Not certain what you mean by _"not as needed."_? What are you trying to achieve which `.not()` does not accomplish?

Comment: Read as "it doesn't fit my needs". This sentence was included to encourage trying to achieve similar result with `:not()` or `.not()`, before actually proposing to use  it.

Comment: What is actual Question?

Comment: "Is there a simple way to perform subtraction between two nodesets in JQuery?"

Comment: Edited a question, trying to make it more clear/less confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following plug-in version. It uses the fact that [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) can accept another jQuery selection:

```js
$.fn.find_exclude = function(original_selector, exclude_selector) {
    return $(this).find(original_selector).not(exclude_selector)
            .not($(this).find(exclude_selector).find(original_selector));
}

$(function(){
  var all_b_in_main_not_in_groups = $("#main").find_exclude('b','.group');
  all_b_in_main_not_in_groups.css('color', 'red');

  var all_b_in_inner_not_in_groups = $("#inner").find_exclude('b','.group');
  all_b_in_inner_not_in_groups.css('opacity', '0.5');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="main">
    <b>I should be red</b>
    <div class="group" id="inner">
      <span>
        <b>I should be opaque but not red</b>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <b>I should be red</b>
      <div class="group">
         <b>Don't touch me, please.</b>
            <div>
              <b>Don't touch me, please.</b>
                <p>
                  <b>Don't touch me, please.</b>
                </p>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

The last `.not()` is the main part: it excludes nodes that are descendants of the to-be-excluded parents. In case a node satisfies both the original and the exclude selector, it would not be excluded by this `.not()` and so another `.not()` (the first one) is applied for dealing with those cases.

Not related to your question, but note that you don't need the `.each()` loops to apply the `.css()` method call. You can apply it directly to a jQuery selection.

#### Alternative: not searching excluded sub-trees

In comments you asked whether it would be possible to perform a search that does not need to first match all nodes by the original selector, to then remove those that should be excluded in line with the exclusion selector.

This you could do by performing the node search with a recursive function call (depth-first search), while omitting that recursive search when arriving at a node that must be excluded:

```
$.fn.find_exclude = function(original_selector, exclude_selector) {
    if ($(this).length == 0) return $();
    var $elems = $(this).children().not(exclude_selector);
    return $elems.filter(original_selector)
                 .add($elems.find_exclude(original_selector, exclude_selector));
}
```

Note however that the DOM API is relatively fast in finding nodes with selectors (cf. [`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) used by jQuery), so doing it "yourself" with this alternative comes with some overhead, which in the end might be more time-expensive than when using the first method. This depends on how large the subtrees are below the to-be-excluded nodes. The larger they are, the more probable it is that the alternative recursive method performs better. But I guess in "normal" situations the first solution will be faster.

Comment: I liked your answer - I'm not quite sure how, but it works. I'll investigate a bit to check, if isn't it too much traversing, of which I was trying to get rid in the first place. You seem to be qualified enough, so please answer: are you sure, that in my case there is no actual way to prevent including something into collection, rather than subtracting it later? I mean without  rewriting/modifying jquery's original `.find()`.

Comment: I would not know of a single selector to achieve this. I suppose if it exists that it will still make jQuery collect all matching nodes to then exclude those that are descendants of excluded nodes. I provided another alternative to my answer that really does not visit nodes when they are in such subtrees, but performance might vary.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. > you don't need the `.each()` loops to apply the `.css()`... I know this, the part of the question, which says, that `.css()` isn't actually what I need those nodes for is lost in question edits.

Answer (score 2):

```
function customFind (findWhere, findWhat, ignoreWhat){
    var totalIgnore = $(findWhere).find(ignoreWhat + ' ' + findWhat);
    return $(findWhere).find(findWhat).not(totalIgnore);
}
```

Use:

```
var zzz= customFind(this,"b",".group");
zzz.css('text-decoration','underline');
```

Comment: You use id's. Please reread (i've edited the question some time ago) "IDs are not actually present in the code, they're added purely for demonstrational purposes ("starting node" gets picked by user)."

Comment: P.S.: Sorry for not-very-well given example with such restrictions - actual code/HTML is too complicated, so I tried to simplify, without losing the main idea. Plus what if i want, `$(this).find('input, textarea,button')` - i will need to include them in `not()` each time i need smth else? I was asking for a general solution (subtracting sets).

Comment: Excuse me, I'm not trying to be picky, but the main problem is I can't know `containerSelector` beforeahead >("starting node" gets picked by user). So only thing I have is `$(this)` for starting node.

Comment: @haldagan how about now?

Comment: Sorry again for confusingly worded question at the start. I give you a + but trincot's answer is actually more accurate. As I mentioned before - I wanted a general solution. In your case something like `findWhat="input,textarea,button"` just won't work (as `.find(ignoreWhat+' '+findWhat)` will become `.find('.something input,textarea,button')`), which will return the same as `.find('.something input')` plus `.find('textarea')` plus `.find('button')`, instead of desirable `.find('.something input, .something textarea, .something button')`